# Image resources not showing react-native (Navbar and tabbar)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

When I debug the app on my phone or emulator the icons show on the navbar and tabbar, when I close the app and unplug the phone and run the app again the icons do not show anymore.

**Here is my navigation buttons:**

```
static navigatorButtons = {
        rightButtons: [
            {
                icon: require('../../assets/ic_account.png'),
                id: 'btnAccount',
                showAsAction: 'always',
                title: 'Account'
            },
            {
                icon: require('../../assets/ic_event.png'),
                id: 'btnSwitch',
                showAsAction: 'always',
                title: 'Switch Event'
            }
        ]
    };
```

**Here is my tabs for the navbar:**

```
const tabs = [
    {
        label: 'Scan',
        screen: 'myscreens.ScanScreen', 
        icon: require('./assets/ic_camera.png'),
        selectedIcon: require('./assets/ic_camera.png'), 
        title: 'Scan'
    },
    {
        label: 'Search',
        screen: 'myscreens.SearchScreen',
        icon: require('./assets/ic_search.png'),
        selectedIcon: require('./assets/ic_search.png'), 
        title: 'Search'
    } 
];
```

**And here is my navigation:**

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    tabs,
    tabsStyle: {
        tabBarBackgroundColor: '#DBDBDB',
        navBarButtonColor: '#FFF',
        tabBarButtonColor: '#888',
        navBarTextColor: '#ffffff',
        tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#444',
        navigationBarColor: '#000',
        navBarBackgroundColor: '#444',
        statusBarColor: '#444',
        tabFontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
        forceTitlesDisplay: true
    },
    appStyle: {
        tabBarBackgroundColor: '#DBDBDB',
        navBarButtonColor: '#FFF',
        tabBarButtonColor: '#888',
        navBarTextColor: '#ffffff',
        tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#444',
        navigationBarColor: '#000',
        navBarBackgroundColor: '#444',
        statusBarColor: '#444',
        tabFontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
        forceTitlesDisplay: true
    }
});
```

Before unplugging the device:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFjZK.png)

After unplugging the device:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV5P8.png)

The app is still in debug mode and using the debug apk. Tested on multiple devices with the same result, using Android API 19-25.

**UPDATE:** I have found that it happens only in the debug build of the app, when I do a release build then all icons on the Tabbar and navbar are showing as they should.

Comment: try formatting where in startTabBasedApp() you add array directly, not previously created object. Like this:
tabs: [
                        {
                            label: strings.home,
                            screen: 'view.HomeScreen',
                            icon: require('../img/icons/xxhdpi/home_grey_xxhdpi.png'),
                            title: strings.home
                        }]

Comment: @Medardas tried that, still not working

Comment: that is weird... try maybe cleaning android project and rebuilding it. maybe even node_modules. There is a chance something has corrupted during build time. Another probable reason can be that react-native is not good friends with your particular phone. how does it look on emulator? (simulate unplugging by killing dev server)

Comment: @Medardas on the emulator it shows the icons, it is only when it runs on a device when the icons are not showing, I am using a Nexus 6P running android 7.1.2

Comment: have exactly same setup, but it works for me. Can also be something wrong with react-native-navigation version. Try to update

Comment: updated to latest version, still not working, could it be the way I require the image resource or the directory structure ?

Comment: @Vincent did you find a solution to this? I am having exactly the same issue

Comment: @Newm I found that it occurs only in the debug build, if you do a release build then everything shows as they should, no solution for debug build yet sadly